# melhor maneira de criar uma galeria de videos

Tags: php, html5, vídeo

Estou estudando PHP, HTML 5 e CSS.

Gostaria de  saber qual melhor maneira de criar uma espécie de galeria ou grade de vídeos bem organizada e qual melhor linguagem para isso.

Comment: Assim uma dica seria você vir com perguntas sobre o código, exemplo: Você tem um script X que era pra somar números mas tem algum erro que você não consegue enxergar .
Ai você vem aqui pede ajuda para um possível solução .

Comment: Slideshow desse site http://kithomepage.com/kit/scripts/janelas/colorbox/exemplos/colorbox.php   OU Image gallery desse site http://fancybox.net/  OU desse http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/

Comment: Depende do seu gosto e recursos da sua hospedagem atual (ela precisará ter o PHP instalado e configurado caso queira utilizar junto a uma base de dados como por exemplo interação de cadastros com mysqli), você pode fazer isso usando PHP, HTML 5 e CSS ou apenas HTML, CSS e JQuery, para dar um "charme" especial use o jQuery já que tem uns efeitos bem bacana. Veja esses exemplos de jquery bem atraentes:
http://visuallightbox.com/content/30-best-image-sliders-173.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você poderia usar o CSS do [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) organizando os videos dentro das classes como "col-md-6" você consegue colocar  dois videos lado a lado em duas divs usando essa classe.

Comment: Poderia colocar um exemplo básico, ficaria bom.

Comment: Desculpe  @Everson,  pensei que seria mais pratico e menos falho passar assim para ele, sou novato também e recentemente pesquisei sobre e usei o Bootstrap, por esse motivo apenas passei o link